# Using Electric Motor/Generator Instead of Inverter to Deliver AC Mains from Batteries / Solar

Tags: solar-cell, inverter, generator

I am exploring/researching Solar PV systems and the possibility of setting up a solar installation company. **DC/AC inverters are very expensive and I am trying to find a cheaper solution.**

**Question:** How feasible is it to remove the Inverter from the solar setup and instead use the battery bank to power a motor that is directly coupled to an AC generator to deliver AC mains power to a house?

Comment: The motors of the size you'll need will be comparable in cost to the inverter.

Comment: when your inverter dies because of surging , spikes , lightening , transients , or a EMF the robustness of a M/G set up will pay for itself.

Comment: What would the likelihood of an inverter being destroyed by one of these events be? I have not heard of many cases of inverters dying before their suggested lifespan.

Comment: And... in order to make an MG set function for this, you need the ability to control the speed of it and the DC voltage coming into it, so you STILL end up with a control system that is subject to the exact same risks as the inverter. With the inverter, you have not ADDED the maintenance issues of the motor and generator.

Comment: You ever get any closure on this?

Comment: If you want to go cheap mechanical, you don't need a motor-generator for this, just a simple commutator to flip the leads on your DC source back and forth.  Since it's not actually generating power this can be spun by a tiny motor and since it's not actually taking the electrical load you won't need fancy speed control circuits.  Then just put the power through a transformer to get the voltage you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is called a motor-generator set. The idea is well-known and has been used widely, although not so much for DC to AC conversion. Compared to solid-state inverters, though, they have a number of problems. First, mechanical wear and maintenance are a major factor in operational cost and reliability. Bearings and brushes wear out. Second, locking the output frequency to the line frequency to allow co-generation is much easier with inverters.

For private use, a motor-generator is simply not a good idea. Not only is it more expensive than an inverter, private home-owners are not likely to perform the periodic maintenance (especially lubrication) that the system will require. When the system then fails, your company will be blamed for providing a shoddy product.

Comment: Yup. Ward-lenard setup. But the efficiency is shocking. The OP will pay for it elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you're doing, you can build a decent dc -> ac generator using off-the-shelf or refurbished/free components.  Consider for example an automobile alternator that can deliver 200Amps at 12V.  If you remove the rectifying diodes, you're left with a 3-phase ac generator that can deliver about 2KW without overheating (200A x 12V = 2400W).

Each of the 3-phases can provide a full 15 or 20Amp line at 120Vac.  You'll still need a field current circuit (easy) and speed regulating circuit (a little more difficult) with feedback to the motor control unit.  A microprocessor can be used to monitor the output voltage (through a voltage divider/rectifier of course) and provide PWM to the field coil of the alternator and finally to control speed of the drive motor.

You'll still need to find a good drive motor and a motor controller that can be controlled by the pwm or digitally.  Larger R/C or cheap e-bike motors might fit this bill.  A setup like this can easily drive computers, lights, a refrigerator, perhaps a window ac unit and charge batteries for power tools etc.

You **would not** want to grid tie this though unless you have a phase comparator to show the phase difference between your generator line and the mains line.  Only when the phases are synched can you connect them and if they are too far out of synch, you will blow relays or break something. But really, why would you want to do that?  At 2KW, you really are only making enough power for personal use, and much beyond that you need large batteries and many solar panels to charge them. In fact, I've found it's better to drive everything you can directly off DC.

Cheap buck/boost converters can increase or decrease the dc voltage to match the need of individual devices for computers, lights etc. Really only large inductive loads need a/c and many times you can find dc versions of those as well (think RV refrigerator, ductless mini-splits, etc).

Comment: How efficient do you think a system like this could be?

Comment: And why would you use an alternator when you could use a BLDC and skip having to have an additional component to spin the alternator?

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of powering your house with a solar chated battery. or just doing grid-tie?  For the former, you need low no-load consumption to keep power on at night witjput flattening your battery.
DC motor efficiency is only about 85% at 1kw but rises to maybe 93% at 10kw. Alternator efficiency is similar so the combined efficiency is about 70% at 1kw or 87% at 10kw, compared to an inverter's 95% plus.
However, the motor generstor power does not go down much on low loads, as it still has to spin at full speed, so its no-load consumption is high.  So you are best off using a solid state inverter for that job, like an AIMS 8kw splu-phse 120-0-120 producz ($1900 approx)
Grid tie is a little different. It can't power your house as it has to switch off if the grid is down. It just feeds power back to the grid and winds your meter backwards when the sun shines.. It uses all the solar panel power all the time so the need for low no-load consumption is not so important. For high power applications of 100kw or more it is possible that a rotary inverzer could be economic. See here;
https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2016033394A1/en

Comment: BTW  for solar installation you wneed an electricians licence ( electrical contractors licence) and probably  NABCEP  or people with NABCEP certification trained in how properly to mount solar panels on a residentisl roof according to local code. You should also be familiar with the latest NEC code (which yiu have to pass a 6 hour exam on to get your electrician's certification)  If you are not there yet, your local community college may offer low cost courses to get you there. I did that and it was well worthwhile. I learned a lot even though I have a Bsc and doctorate in electronics already.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Paul. Tip: there's no need to comment on your own question - you can use the [Edit] link to add content. Also 'kW', not 'kw' as per SI standards.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting,
My advice is, add flywheel mass, this will reduce drop of RPM for a sudden spike from load, for example during starting an induction motor (air conditioner, washing machine, compressor refrigerant, etc.). A flywheel works well like capacitor.

For DC control, you can use a BLDC (Brushless DC Motor), this will reduce maintenance need for carbon brush, also a BLDC motor can vary for trigger current, by need, customize during low load, or high load, it can be adjustable. So battery consumption may be varied to distribute power to BLDC motor, as needed only.

Only concern is efficiency.

Also, [here's a reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330184905_Utilization_of_DC_motor-AC_generator_system_to_convert_the_solar_direct_current_into_220v_alternating_current).

Keep innovate,

Answer (score 0):

It may be "cheaper" to MacGyver a MG solution for DC/AC conversion but you will never reach the efficiency of a good inverter. On top you will face the challenges of speed control when you have fast load changes.

As an off-grid solution with limited funds and enough useable motors and skill laying about, I'd say go for it. But as a commercial solution the Inverter isn't that widely abundant for no reason.